# Logged into Sonata admin but authorization checker in controller returns false

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm working with `Symfony CMF`, `Sonata Admin`, `Sonata UserBundle`, and `FOS UserBundle`. I can login to the back-end and manage entities for the site. However in my front-end controllers when checking for a logged in user with...

```
if ( ! $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    exit('not logged in');
}
```

... the 'not logged in' termination gets fired.

I'm not sure whether I'm using the right method to check the user is authenticated, or whether I have missed something when configuring `Sonata UserBundle`.

**UPDATE** (addition of firewalls)

config.yml

```
# FOS User Bundle
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
  group:
    group_class: Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
  registration:
    form:
      type: application_sonata_user_registration
```

security.yml

```
security:
  firewalls:

    # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
    admin:
      pattern:      /admin(.*)
      form_login:
        provider:       fos_userbundle
        login_path:     /admin/login
        use_forward:    false
        check_path:     /admin/login_check
        failure_path:   null
      logout:
        path:           /admin/logout
      anonymous:    true
    # -> end custom configuration

    # defaut login area for standard users
    main:
      pattern:      .*
      form_login:
        provider:       fos_userbundle
        login_path:     /login
        use_forward:    false
        check_path:     /login_check
        failure_path:   null
      logout:       true
      anonymous:    true
```

Comment: Probably you have two firewalls.

Comment: One more possibility is that you logged in by remember me token, that way `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` return false, you should check by `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`.

Comment: Definitely wasn't remember me... I had to enter my credentials.

Comment: So I guess that you have two firewalls front, back, and you not set `context` to them.

Comment: ... added them above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two security systems, when you logged in admin, you're not authenticated in main firewall and vice versa. If you want use multiple firewalls for one session you can use `context` option http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context

Add to each firewall:

```
context: main
```